# Can i deliver ffdshow with my application

Tags: ffdshow

Can i deliver ffdshow with my application. Is there any license issues.
I am developing a media application , in which i want to play different types of videos
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

ffdshow-tryouts (http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow-tryout/), which is the currently actively developed ffdshow is GPL. I think you would have to make your application GPL as well if you are going to build on top of it...

See what GPL is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License

I am no lawyer though... read the wikipedia page, I think your answer is in there (don't know what app you have and how much of ffdshow it is going to use etc...)